# Is there any way to install MPV without having to compile it from source?

Tags: software-installation, video-player

Hello does any know about/or have a [`mpv`](http://mpv.io) package compiled for 13.04?

I have searched for a PPA without any luck.

Answer (score 8):

Debian offers the mpv package since Jessie, and it's available on testing/unstable, so it should be included in [universe repositories](http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/xenial/mpv), as Ubuntu imports unstable repositories for non-LTS releases, and testing for LTS. Just make sure you have the [universe repository enabled](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu#Adding_Repositories_in_Ubuntu), your package lists updated, and run `sudo apt-get install mpv`.

Answer (score 5):

This ppa seems to work (I just tried it): https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/mpv-tests/

There is also a bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1208633 and I hope they sync it for Trusty, it really looks promising.

Comment: only you cannot set mpv as default to open video files.

Comment: with gtk-3.10 (trusty), .desktops that contain NoDisplay=true can now show up in Details > default apps.. mpv itself needs a better .desktop than supplied to be available, the ones in my ppa are adjusted for this by adding 2 mimes, 1 for video, 1 for audio (and also extended for DnD on most supported mimetypes.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a ppa.

- https://launchpad.net/~blinxwang/+archive/mpv-builds

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:blinxwang/mpv-builds
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install mpv
  ```